# How to write a message on info bar, mail read window?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I'm writing an outlook addin with c# to  integrate outlook to our helpdesk system. When user clicks in a button on the ribbon some information in this message (if it is a support request) are sent to our help desk system through webservices. 
Everything is working fine but i'd like to notify the user if the current message had already sent to hel desk. I'd like to do this same manner outlook does to notify you if you had already answered an email, like the picture below:
[i'd like to write a message in this highlighted area](http://s23.postimg.org/9uuffk7uj/notificacao.png)

I don't know how this area is called in outlook api, so I can't do a good research on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That area is not exposed. But you can try to set a category - it will be shown in the area above the message header.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook extensibiliy model doesn't provide anything for that. Possible workarounds are:

1. You may consider using Outlook Form Regions in the add-in project. But they don't provide such layout. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) for more information.
2. You may also consider using Windows API functions for subclassing Outlook windows and inserting your own form. See [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx) for more information.
3. Add-in Express provides [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions.php).

Comment: Although your   answer  is more accurate, I think I can try to set a color or a category on these messages so they can be kind of "flagged " in an easier way.  Thanks.